# Tableview doesn't scroll inside the scrollview? what is the reason for this?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, tableview

I have added a table view inside the UIView. This UIView is added to the scrollView.Now the problem in the tableview doesn't scroll and the cell isn't clickable. What is the reason? and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UIView will not scroll because it contains UITableView.

Whenever you try to scroll, tableview will scroll instead of your scrollview.